# can´t run roscore - unable to contact my own server

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, odroid, ssh, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am pretty new at ROS and I have to work on Odroid for my project.
ROS is installed on my Odroid and it was working sort of fine until I wanted to create SSH connection with the computer.
I want to attach the odroid on a robot and run the command from my computer.

But at the moment, even while the Odroid is not attached to the robot, I can´t run roscore on it. It gives me the following error:

```
Unable to contact my own server at [http://192.168.1.105:44827/]
This usually means that the network is not configured properly.
A common cause is that th machine cannot ping itself. Please check for errors by running:
ping 192.168.1.105
```

On my odriod when I type `hostname -I` to learn the IP it gives me:

```
192.168.1.225
```

when I check the bashrc file on odroid it says

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.105:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.105
```

Meanwhile on my main computer that I want to give the command, the result for `hostname -I`

```
10.1.214.229
```

The bashrc file:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.105:11311/
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.21
```

I want to find solution firstly why I can not run roscore on my odroid and then where do i do wrong with my IP setting?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301509/can%C2%B4t-run-roscore---unable-to-contact-my-own-server/) by [firuze](https://answers.ros.org/users/36776/firuze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-08-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`192.168.1.105` is not the IP of your Odroid (any more).

It could have been earlier, but according to your `hostname -I` output, it is now `192.168.1.225`.

You're setting `ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.105`, which makes `roscore` try and use that to connect to "its own server". This will obviously fail.

Try to set `ROS_HOSTNAME` to `192.168.1.225`. Save `.bashrc`, open a new terminal and try again.

Note: using `ROS_HOSTNAME` like this is actually why things are failing for you. You can avoid this by configuring a static IP for your Odroid (either locally on the device itself, or by making a DHCP "reservation" in your router).

The better alternative would be to make sure you have a working DNS on your network.

That would allow you to use hostnames instead of IP addresses. The IP addresses can then change, but the hostnames stay the same.

A middleground could be to use `/etc/hosts`: you configure the mapping `IP<->hostname` there manually. You'd still be responsible for keeping that file up-to-date though.

A third alternative could be to use Avahi to do name resolution for you. See [wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup: Name resolution - Using machinename.local](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Using_machinename.local) on the ROS wiki for some more info on that.

And make sure to check the [wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) page for more general info about how to configure your network correctly.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-24**:
Edit: I should have closed this as a duplicate. There are quite a few older questions about this. Using Google I get [these results](https://www.google.nl/search?q=cannot+contact+my+own+server++site%3Aanswers.ros.org) fi.

**Comment by [firuze](https://answers.ros.org/users/36776/firuze/) on 2018-08-24**:
I checked similar questions but couldn´t solve my problem from given answers.. thank you for not closing it